# How do I vertically centering text inside a responsive box that has a (fluid height)

Tags: css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I am building a responsive website and am using a grid system. The grid boxes of course do not have a set height. they are fluid. The image that is placed within them will define the height ad then it will scale with the available width of the viewport

What I am trying to do is lay text **over** the image and vertically align the text in the middle of the image.

I have read a ton of posts out there on vertical aligning but none seem to address doing it with a responsive box.

I set up a fiddle using the only the condensed css necessary to replicate my grid system for this example. I am using 2 grey dummy images. I want to lay text **over** them and align the text vertically.  How would this be done? Any ideas? Id prefer to do this only with css unless jquery is absolutely needed but I think css alone can do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/zjDuE/

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="row">
<div class="c6"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/cccccc/cccccc.jpg" alt="-" /></div>
<div class="c6"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/cccccc/cccccc.jpg" alt="-" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think my codepen could be usefull for you.

http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/gLebo

Try to use vertical-alight with `display: table-cell`
and your center vertical align will work for fluid heights.
Good luck :)

[Support for `table-*`](http://caniuse.com/#search=table)

Comment: Thank you very much for setting up the codepen. The issue is that I still think that will not work based on the specific instance that I have setup on my jsfiddle link for you.  There is an image already in the responsive div so I need to lay the text over that image and i assume i would need to use absolute positioning to stack on top of the image.  If you look at my jsfiddle url, those grey boxes represent images. I need to lay the text over the images and vertical align the text.

Comment: With pure css I dont its possible but I did for you example on your fiddle with jQuery. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fFx8/) out, hope it helps :)

Comment: That is excellent! Just what I was trying to do. Thank you very much for helping me with that. I really appreciate you're time and help on this!

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution for centering two lines of text within a module in a a grid-based responsive template, based on the good info presented here. Thanks so much!

```
<ul>
<li class="v-centertext">
<div class="v-font140">Call Us (Toll Free):
<div class="v-font200">866-944-xxxx
</div></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

here is css:

```
.v-centertext {position: relative;display: table; text-align: center;}
.v-centertext div {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;}
.v-font140 {font-size: 140%; line-height: 1.2em;}
.v-font200 {font-size: 200%; line-height: 1.3em; color: #00679d;}
```